# Making a "reversed" Cluster Dendogram with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a reversed Cluster Dendrogram, it has both many parents and the parents are sometimes connected to same children. Imagine a tournament elimination bracket to get the idea what I am trying to do. I've been experimenting with [Mbostock's Dendrogram example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570) but my two parent nodes are overwriting each other.
I have a simple [test here](https://jsfiddle.net/svenakela/ynLmdjmz/16/) with three "root" nodes.

```
var testData = {
    "name":"First",  "children": [{"name":"Third", "children":[]}],
    "name":"Second", "children": [{"name":"Third", "children":[]}],
    "name":"Fourth", "children": []
};
```

Like the test data above there are parents that aren't related to any children (yet), still I would like to get them on the same level. Is there any simple solution to separate the parents vertically? I would like to make a graph like:

```
First ──┐     
        ├── Third   
Second ─┘

Fourth ─
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversed the source tree, starting with the last node as the root (ie Third) and then mirrored the structure with a transform. 
A working example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ynLmdjmz/20/).

```
var testData = {"name":"LAST", 
            "children": [...
```